# bat/cmd file to set java home path

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to easily switch between different java versions and therefore want to set home path and path at system level in enviroment variables by running a bat/cmd file.

My .bat file looks like this:

```
@echo off  
echo Setting JAVA_HOME  
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0
echo JAVA_HOME: %JAVA_HOME% 
echo setting PATH
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH% 
echo PATH: %PATH%
```

If i type echo %JAVA_HOME% in same commandprompt then it prints the path to jdk1.8.0 but not if i open up a new commandprompt, also if i look in enviroment variables it is not listed there.

EDIT: I've also tried

```
@echo off  
echo Setting JAVA_HOME  
setx JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0"
echo JAVA_HOME: %JAVA_HOME% 
echo setting PATH
setx PATH "%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%"
echo PATH: %PATH%  
echo Display java version  
java -version
```

And this works, at the user level, but not at the system level.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved it by:

```
@echo off  
echo Setting JAVA_HOME  
setx -m JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0"
echo JAVA_HOME: %JAVA_HOME% 
echo setting PATH
setx -m PATH "%Path%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin"
echo PATH: %PATH%  
echo Display java version  
java -version  
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that setx does not have an = sign.  If you have

```
setx abc=def
```

It will set the variable abc=def to nothing.  If you wish to set abc to def, the syntax is

```
setx abc def
```

What you are seeing is the correct behaviour when you run the batch file with set.  To set the environment variables globally

```
@echo off  
echo Setting JAVA_HOME  
setx JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0"
echo JAVA_HOME: %JAVA_HOME% 
echo setting PATH
setx PATH %JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH% 
echo PATH: %PATH%
```

Note that there is no = after the variable when you use setx

Comment: Thank, you. I've already tried that, and that works at the user level. But not at the system level.

Comment: For a system level variable, use setx /m